# For which values of $\alpha$ is the solution stable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If we have the following differential equation

$X'=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & \alpha  \end{bmatrix}X$

for which values of $\alpha$ is the zero solution stable?

**My attempt**: For stability we need the real part of all eigenvalues to be negative and geometric and algebraic multiplicity to be the same.I tried computing the eigenvalues and see the different cases but it is an incredible amount of work and I got stuck.

Would there be any simpler and nicer way to do this(with knowledge of a first course in ODE)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This question is essentially about linear algebra, namely, analyzing the eigenvalues of the matrix, call it $A$, as a function of the (presumptively real) parameter $\alpha$.

The characteristic polynomial of the matrix, whose roots are the eigenvalues $\lambda, \mu$ of $A$, is
$$p(t) := \det(t I - A) = t^2 - (\alpha + 1) t + (\alpha + 1) .$$ Thus, $\lambda + \mu = \lambda \mu = \alpha + 1$. But if both $\lambda$ and $\mu$ have negative real part, then $\alpha + 1 = \lambda + \mu < 0 < \lambda \mu = \alpha + 1$, a contradiction.

**Remark** The claim is in particular valid even when the roots $\lambda, \mu$ are not real. In that case---which occurs precisely when the discriminant $\alpha^2 - 2 \alpha - 3 = (\alpha + 1)(\alpha - 3)$ of $p(t)$ is negative, i.e., when $\alpha \in (-1, 3)$---the roots are complex conjugates, say, $\beta \pm \gamma i$, where $\beta, \gamma \in \Bbb R$. If the common real part, $\beta$, of the roots is negative, then their sum, $\alpha + 1 = 2 \beta$, is negative but their product, $\alpha + 1 = \beta^2 + \gamma^2$, is positive, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, i don't understand this part "λ+μ=λμ=α+1"

Comment: If $\lambda, \mu$ are the roots of $t^2 + b t + c$, we have $t^2 + b t + c = (t - \lambda) (t - \mu) = t^2 - (\lambda + \mu) t  + \lambda \mu$, so comparing coefficients gives $-b = \lambda + \mu$ and $c = \lambda \mu$. In our case, $-b = c = \alpha + 1$.

Comment: I think you have to be more careful with the conclusion $\lambda + \mu < 0 < \lambda \mu$. First of all, you need to argue that the values are real to give meaning to the inequalities. I guess this is doable since the non-real roots of a real polynomial occur in conjugate pairs. Then you have to argue why the product $\lambda\mu$ is positive: Note that there are complex numbers $u,v \in \mathbb{C}$ with negative real parts such that their product also has negative real part, e.g. $u = v = -1 + 2i$. I guess the "conjugate-pair-argument" works again.

Comment: @iljusch As far as I can tell, you've addressed your own objection: Since the characteristic polynomial $p(t)$ is real, so are $\lambda + \mu$ and $\lambda \mu$, because they are (up to sign) the non-leading coefficients of the polynomial, hence it makes sense to compare them with other real numbers with inequalities. Like you write, in the case that $\lambda, \mu$ are conjugates, say, $\rho \pm \sigma i$, $\lambda$ and $\mu$ have real part $\rho$, and $\lambda \mu = \rho^2 + \sigma^2$, which establishes the claimed inequalities. Am I overlooking something in your comment?

Comment: @Travis I agree, but may I ask you to include it in your argumentation? Without this additional insight the conclusion is unclear and might give undergraduate students the wrong idea of how complex numbers work.
Also, sorry for the inconsiderate downvote, which I could not withdraw afterwards (unless you edit your answer, in which case I can finally change it).

Comment: @iljusch No worries, I've added a remark as you suggested. I've also added a parenthetical comment emphasizing that the approach assumes that $\alpha$ itself is real, which is typical for OP's context ("knowledge of a first course in ODE").